# How to close Redis pub/sub connection with Server-Sent Events

Tags: php, redis, real-time

I had used Server-Sent Events with php and redis pub/sub create a real-time application. But looks like when you refresh your page. The redis pub/sub connection is not closed. I check my server, the redis connection number is not going down. The redis connection number is increased when you refresh your page.

`netstat -an | grep :6379 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l`

I will use the following command to kill all redis sub/pub connection, but this is not a good way to control it. So anyone has a good idea for it?

`redis-cli CLIENT KILL TYPE pubsub`

Answer (score 0):

Figure out :

`redis-cli client list | grep cmd=subscribe | grep  $PRODUCTION_1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk '{print "CLIENT KILL ID " $0}' | redis-cli -x`